# py.test traceback path display

Tags: python, pytest

Currently when py.test prints tracebacks, it either prints a full path such as:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py:744:
```

...or it prints a path from the directory that it's run from, such as:

```
delphi/delphi/model/risk_manager.py:176:
```

...or it prints a relative path with `.` relative to the directory it's run from:

```
../delphi/delphi/model/pca_model.py:56:
```

Because I'm using PyCharm, I can only click on these if they're the full path. It's really helpful to be able to click on a link and go straight to the code, rather than manually navigating there on each link.

Is there a way of forcing py.test to print the full path? Or even if anyone has insight into what causes the various option above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Humm I don't think there is a way to tell pytest to print as you like.
But there is a plugin for pytest-pycharm that should help you : pytest-pycharm

```
$ pip install pytest-pycharm
```

I never used this plugin because I work with vim =) but let me if this works.

Comment: The plugin is great, but doesn't help with this problem

Comment: OKay, sorry that I can't help you for now.